# Compare 2 lists and determine the records with unique column data

Tags: java, list

I have a class with the following properties:

Class name: Recs

Properties: String Code, String Name

I have a 2 list with a sample data:

```
List<Recs> dbDataList = new List<Recs>();
dbDataList.add(new Recs("001", "A");
dbDataList.add(new Recs("002", "B");
dbDataList.add(new Recs("003", "C");

List<Recs> genDataList = new List<Recs>();
genDataList.add(new Recs("001", "A");
genDataList.add(new Recs("002", "B");
genDataList.add(new Recs("003", "C");
genDataList.add(new Recs("004", "A");
genDataList.add(new Recs("005", "A");
```

The records in genDataList that have a Code not yet existing in the dbDataList should be added in a new list called uniqueList. For debugging purposes, I would also like to add the non-unique codes in duplicateList

uniqueList should include the records below:

("004", "A")

("005", "A")

duplicateList should include the records below:

("001", "A")

("002", "B")

("003", "C")

Is there a way to do this without looping the List? I can't seem to find List functions that can filter specific column to get the unique/non-unique value of a specific column from another list.

Answer (score 0):

you can use code like this :

```
    for(Recs db : dbDataList)
    {
        for(Recs gen : genDataList)
        {
            if(db.code.equals(gen.code) && db.name.equals(gen.name))
            {
                duplicateList.add(db);
                genDataList.remove(gen);
                break;
            }
            else
                uniqueList.add(db);
        }
    }
    for(Recs r : genDataList)
    {
        uniqueList.add(r);
    }
```